# LINQ in typescript or any alternative

Tags: angular, typescript, linq

I have the following code in c# that i want to use in typescript to show data in grid. Is there any way that i can run the following LINQ code in typescript? if not exactly , are there any workarounds?

```
var repaymentplan1 = from repaymentplan in AssetsRepaymentPlan.m_current
    group repaymentplan by new
    {
        repaymentplan.PRPLRPMTPLAN.REPAYMENTPLANID,
        repaymentplan.PRPLRPMTPLAN.RENTALDTE
    } into g

    select new
    {
        REPAYMENTPLANID = g.Key.REPAYMENTPLANID,
        CONTRACTDUEDATE = g.Key.RENTALDTE,
        CONTRACTINTERESTAMOUNT = g.Sum(repaymentplan => repaymentplan.PRPLRPMTPLAN.INTERESTAMT),
        CONTRACTPRINCIPALAMOUNT = g.Sum(repaymentplan => repaymentplan.PRPLRPMTPLAN.PRINCIPALAMT),
        CONTRACTPRINCIPALOSAMOUNT = g.Sum(repaymentplan => repaymentplan.PRPLRPMTPLAN.PRINCIPALOUTSTANDINGAMT),
        CONTRACTRENTALAMT = g.Sum(repaymentplan => repaymentplan.PRPLRPMTPLAN.RENTALAMT),
        CONTRACTRENTALTAX = g.Sum(repaymentplan => repaymentplan.PRPLRPMTPLAN.GSTAMT),
        CMPRECEIVABLEAMT = g.Sum(repaymentplan => repaymentplan.PRPLRPMTPLAN.RENTALAMT),
        REGISTRATIONAMT = g.Sum(repaymentplan => repaymentplan.PRPLRPMTPLAN.REGISTRATIONAMT),
        INSURANCEAMT = g.Sum(repaymentplan => repaymentplan.PRPLRPMTPLAN.INSURANCEAMT),
        g.FirstOrDefault().PRPLRPMTPLAN.CHARGEAMT,
        TaxDetail = from taxDetails in g.Select(a => a.PRPLRPMTPLANTAX)
                    from taxDetail in taxDetails
                    group taxDetail by new
                    {
                        taxDetail.TAXTYPECDE,
                        taxDetail.AMNTCMPTCDE,
                        taxDetail.TAXRATE
                    } into gt
                    select new
                    {
                        gt.Key.AMNTCMPTCDE,
                        gt.Key.TAXTYPECDE,
                        gt.Key.TAXRATE,
                        BASEAMT = gt.Sum(tax => tax.BASEAMT),
                        TAXAMT = gt.Sum(tax => tax.TAXAMT),
                        CMPTTAXRCBLAMT = gt.Sum(tax => tax.CMPTTAXRCBLAMT),
                        ITCAMT = gt.Sum(tax => tax.ITCAMT),
                        ITCPCT = gt.Sum(tax => tax.ITCPCT),
                        TAXADJTAMT = gt.Sum(tax => tax.TAXADJTAMT),
                        TAXSETLAMT = gt.Sum(tax => tax.TAXSETLAMT)
                    }
    };
```

Comment: generally you call to an API that return the object, else you need work with arrays in javascript using map, foreach and reduce

Comment: I have used [this](https://decembersoft.com/posts/typescript-vs-csharp-linq/) site before to help me get to a good solution in TypeScript.